# Subdomain, a place to check for SQL injection?

Tags: sql-injection

I understand the benefits of cleaning all data and quoting data, etc, but I'm wondering if http allows for a situation where a subdomain could have the right chars for SQL injection.

Comment: Sorry? What do you mean? subdomains (i.e. domains under a domain, like "static.some.domain.com") and sql injection have pretty much nothing to do with each other.

Comment: @TomTom Never mind buddy, we got it covered :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean like http://%27%3B%20delete%20table%20users%3B%20commit%3B.example.com?

I'm guessing you have a wildcard DNS entry and are taking the subdomain as a form of input. If so, then yes, it's user-generated input and you have to be as suspicious of it as anything else. Even if none of us here on SO can come up with a real example for this question, that doesn't mean someone much more determined who spends more time on it couldn't come up with one.

Is there an argument *against* escaping/processing/checking the subdomain name?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't "clean" or quote your data to avoid SQL injection. You should use query parameters.

Comment: ...which is a way of cleaning/quoting your data. Sometimes you have to do it other ways, depending on your DB connector technology and such.

Comment: @TJCrowder: I wouldn't say parameters is a way of cleaning or quoting. I'd say it's a way to not need to clean or quote.

Comment: @John I'm using an ORM that does all the security stuff for me so I can afford to be ignorant anyhow, but I was just curious.

Comment: @Mark +1 for the unicorn. P.S. Your website has a proxy issue ("Bad Gateway Error").